# CSS - Help me understand "constructed stylesheet" and #shadow-root

Tags: css, shadow-dom

I'm in the need of overriding some CSS of an angular widget. And whatever I do my CSS doesn't seem to apply. It seems the widget is loaded into several nodes labeled #shadow-root. I read a bit on it, but I can't figure where these applied styles come from.

[image: example of shadow root]

I don't want to touch the widget in itself if possible, only override these styles from an overlying stylesheet.

Comment: `shadow-dom` components have a different CSS scope. This is by design. That means that the main document CSS won't apply to them - kind of like iFrames, but not really.

I don't know much about angular, but this seems promising https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/overriding-css-properties-of-third-party-components-in-angular-6a57f143b9d7

Comment: These are Web Components. Trying to tinker with them without understanding what they are won't get you far or do more harm. You can't apply an 'overlying' stylesheet; the whole concept of shadowDOM **is** HTML and CSS isolation. Looks like the only thing you can do here is **append a ``<style>`` element** to each and every shadowDOM.